# Add a keyboard shortcut for the Winter Bash dropdown

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

When it comes to inboxes on Stack Exchange, I've gotten pretty used to using the keybaord. I use <kbd>i</kbd> for the inbox, <kbd>r</kbd> for the achievements notifications (rep / badges), and there's even a shortcut for the moderator inbox (<kbd>q</kbd>).

With that in mind, the Winter Bash inbox / notifications break that consistency. There's currently no keybaord shortcut to open it, despite the fact that Winter Bash has been consistently happening for many years at this point. This means that if you want to open it without the mouse, you have to <kbd>tab</kbd> through the site, which can be a pain if your keyboard focus is already somewhere else.

Could we please get a keyboard shortcut for the WB inbox for consistency? I'd suggest <kbd>w</kbd>, but I'm open to alternatives.